# Discover WiFi driver with Ubuntu to install on CentOS 7

Tags: linux, ubuntu, centos, wifi, kernel-modules

I installed CentOS 7 Minimal on a Yoga Pro 2. However, I'm not able to "up" the WiFi device w1p3s0 despite following numerous guides with `ip link`, `nmcli` and `nmtui`.

The same guides work very well when I install Ubuntu Desktop instead on the same Yoga Pro 2.

If there a way I can discover the *proven* wifi driver using Ubuntu Desktop, copy and install it to CentOS 7? I assume the command `ip link set w1p3s0 up` will work well if the correct driver is installed.

Answer (score 1):

- In your hardware specs, find the WLAN make and model.
- Search for driver package for RHEL 7.
- Install that package.

If there is none, then compiling from source will still work.  I would treat compiling from source as a last resort, since you have to repeat the process every time you update the kernel.

Also, when I last put CentOS 7 on a laptop (Dell), I found that I had a Broadcom WLAN card.  They still do not provide an open source driver, and the method for making Broadcom based WLAN cards work is STILL to either compile community driver from source, or install windows driver with a wrapper.  I chose neither and replaced the WLAN card with a cheap replacement (Intel card) from the internets.  Bottom line, replacing the WLAN card with one that 'just works' is a third option, but this costs money, so...

Comment: +1 and my answer deleted, so edited yours to remove any reference to it.

Comment: There's merit in your answer, but just not as a first choice.  Odd fact, as a sysadmin, I've never compiled from source.  The OG admins I work with are shocked at this and think less of me.  However, "compile from source" = manual operation, and manual operations are anathema to a sysadmin.  However, this stack is devoted to Unix and Linux, and is not just sysadmins, so there are plenty here who do not view "compile from source" as a bad thing.

Comment: I'm just a Technical Project Manager keeping his technical skills honed on his private laptop, here on [unix.se] and https://askubuntu.com...  I _used to be_ a SysAdmin and a SysArch though...  **;-)**